# Automatically execute .cmd file requiring user input

Tags: powershell, tfs, cmd, automation

We have a .cmd file we want to be able to execute automatically using Powershell (from TFS Release).

The issue with using `start-process` in Powershell is that execution gets stuck waiting for user input (`Press any key to continue...`).

Is there any way that we can pass variables to this call or call it in a different way where we no longer require user input for this .cmd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Start-Process`.

```
"`n" | & 'C:\path\to\your.cmd'
```

Comment: Thanks. What does the "`n" do then?

Comment: It echoes a linefeed character. Essentially it's "pressing the Enter button programmatically".

Answer (score 0):

Powershell isn't getting stuck, `Start-Process` is working correctly - it's running the process (assume `cmd.exe`) and waiting for that process to terminate before continuing.

`cmd.exe` is prompting for interactive user input (`PAUSE`) before continuing, again working as you have instructed it to.

The issue is you're running non-interactively, and aren't providing the input required to continue.

---

You can update the cmd file and add an optional parameter so you can 'skip' the `PAUSE` when running unattended:

```
if "%1"=="unattended" goto skippause
pause
:skippause
```

then run it using `unattended`:

```
CMD /c c:\folder\file.cmd unattended
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue with this approach is the .cmd does not belong to us, it comes from a third party, so having to modify their .cmd isn't really an approach that would work for us.

Comment: OK, Ansgars solution will be the way to go then :)